# How to setup Docker Stellar Horizon with complete sync over Pubnet?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, stellar.js, horizon

I'm trying to sync my Horizon with complete Catchup i.e all the data since starting of Stellar Horizon Docker

```
    "history_elder_ledger": 1,
    "core_elder_ledger": 1,
```

Using horizon from https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon
I have successfully setup with normal config, however even with following changes in pubnet/core/etc/stellar-core.cfg, still not able able to start from ledger 1/0

```
    CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
```

also tried by removing

```
    CATCHUP_RECENT=8640
```

Please help me out.